# Could not load file or assembly 'AxInterop.DHTMLEDLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a258947a2b308f2f'

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the `DHTMLEDITOR` with my C# Application with windows 7(its working fine with Windows XP),When I try to add an item or editing the existing item i am receiving the below mentioned error with the `DLL AxInterop.DHTMLEDLib,`

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 
'AxInterop.DHTMLEDLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=a258947a2b308f2f' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the 
assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)


File name: 'AxInterop.DHTMLEDLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=a258947a2b308f2f'
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa663363.aspx

Comment: I have tried with this link, but still getting the same error?can you help me

Comment: Have you tried running VS as administrator?

Comment: I have tried it with administrator also, its working in new windows 7 machine but i cannot able to run the same application in my previous windows 7 machine. can any one help?

Comment: I had found the solution for this problem, this is because of using the corrupted Dlls once I replaced the Dlls it worked fine.       Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. Was solved with DHTML Editing Control for Applications Redistributable Package (x86)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8956